# Running Mathematica Notebook files in command mode

Tags: notebooks, scripting, command-line

The question is, how can I run a `.nb` file in the kernel mode of Mathematica? I am not an expert in Mathematica, but one of our users who use this program says that in the GUI mode, he selects all the cells (CTRL+A) and then evaluates the notebook (SHIFT+ENTER). However, he wants to run the program in background.

When I test with `math < file.nb`, the program quickly exits; however, in the GUI mode, the run time is very large actually.

I read other documentation articles about that, but since I am not expert in Mathmatica, I have no idea!

As an example, [solve.nb](http://pastebin.com/9LnZQbYg) file is an input to the command `math -run < solve.nb`. The output is also available [here](http://pastebin.com/jq7N5Qmh).

[image]

I have no idea what the output means :|

## Update

I simply tried to port the solution to Linux. So I wrote a `solve.m` file containing

```
NotebookPauseForEvaluation[nb_] := Module[{},
While[NotebookEvaluatingQ[nb],Pause[1]]];

NotebookEvaluatingQ[nb_]:=Module[{},
SelectionMove[nb,All,Notebook];
Or@@Map["Evaluating"/.#&,Developer`CellInformation[nb]]
];

UsingFrontEnd[
nb = NotebookOpen["/home/mahmood/solve.nb"];
SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
SelectionEvaluate[nb]
NotebookPauseForEvaluation[nb];
NotebookSave[nb];
];

Quit[];
```

Here is the output of what I see

```
mahmood@cluster:~$ MathKernel -noprompt -initfile solve.m 
mahmood@cluster:~$ 
LinkConnect::linkc: -- Message text not found -- (LinkObject[7wkjs_shm, 3, 1])
^C
mahmood@cluster:~$
```

Note that I pressec ^c after several minutes. Also, the is no output file containing th results.

## Update 2

I tried the solution as given by selecting the cells, initialize them and then save the file as `.m`. I did that on a GUI machine. The saved script file contains

```
(* ::Package:: *)
a = 3;    
Solve[x^2 + a*x + 1 == 0, x]
```

As you can see, the last line in the notebook file is not there in the script file. I ran the command and saw

```
mahmood@cluster:~$ /apps/Mathematica/10.3/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/MathematicaScript -script solve3.m 
mahmood@cluster:~$
```

Is that all? There is no output file containing the result

Comment: Either use `math - run < file.nb` or `math -script file.nb`. If you are still in trouble in can post a detailed description of the steps needed to run a `Wolfram Language` program the way you want.

Comment: Make sure your cells are Code cells if you running a notebook.  I general, if you are running in script mode I would recommend making .m (or .wl) files (File > New > Package).

Comment: @mahmood - why do you need to use the notebook?  I run scripts in command mode all the time, and every time what I do is copy the comands from the notebook into a text file and feed that to `math`

Comment: Is there any way to convert a notebook file to script? It seems that the user who works with Mathematica tries the simplest way. Maybe he has complex expression and for that reason he chooses the .nb file

Comment: To convert the notebook to a script open the notebook, select the cells to be executed, on the menu do: Cell, Cell Properties, Initialization Cell.  Then also on the menu do File, Save As... (file type) Wolfram Mathematica Package (.m).  Also see [Wolfram Language Scripts](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframLanguageScripts.html).

Comment: Only input (i.e. code) is exported and only if you mark the input cell as an initialization cell. Output cells are not exported because they contain results, not code to run.  You seem to be running `ls`, not `MathematicaScript`.

Comment: My fault. I fixed that. The command returns to the prompt but there is no output file.

Comment: Has anyone come up with a way to do this without having mathematica installed?  Like a python script which takes a file.nb and converts it to file.m ?

Answer (score 20):

It is not a good idea to try to run *a notebook* in command line mode.  Whether or not it is possible, it is just not a good idea because notebooks can only be handled by the Front End, which is not a command line tool.  If you go this route anyway, expect difficulties.

The usual way is to extract the code you want to run into a plain text `.m` file and run that.

Do this by marking all cells to be exported as initialization cells.  Select them, then choose Cell -> Cell Properties -> Initialization Cell.  Or often simpler: put them under a section header and mark the header as "Initialization Group".

Then use File -> Save As... -> Wolfram Mathematica Package.

When running it as a script in command line mode, use `MathematicaScript -script filename.m` (for some reason `math -script` may not work the same, so don't use that).

Comment: There is no `MathematicaScript`. Files are `math mathematica Mathematica MathKernel mcc wolfram WolframKernel`. Is that important?

Comment: @mahmood What platform are you on?

Comment: Mathematica 10.3 on Centos-6.1

Comment: @mahmood Then MathematicaScript should be there.  Look again carefully and check in `SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries`.  It may not be in the path.  You can also use `WolframScript`, which may be in the path instead.

Comment: I was looking in `Executables/`. Please see UPDATE2 in the original post

Comment: This may be ridiculous but is there any way to use the `FrontEnd` from the command line so no conversion to `.m` is required? Do you have other suggestions for running from the command line? This is inevitable since many users use remote servers from command lines!

Comment: @H.R. It is probably possible in recent versions using `UsingFrontEnd[NotebookEvaluate[...]]`.  But if you are going to run remotely, I strongly recommend *not* using the FE.  It's not that hard to make an `.m` file. Also, the FE *requires* an X server on Linux, so you may need to set up [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) if your server runs Linux.

Comment: Indeed, I am having trouble with `.m` files! :D Please take a look a [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147293/symbolize-does-not-work-in-m-files)

Answer (score 8):

To replicate the Ctrl+A Enter execution behaviour automatically you can run Solve.nb from a package file, say runSolve.m, containing the code below.

While [Wolfram Language Scripts](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframLanguageScripts.html) are straightforward, this method has the advantage that output can be saved in the notebook as if it was being run manually.

To run a notebook and monitor evaluation simultaneously without clashes a second kernel, e.g. *Kernel2*, is required.  It can be set up via the Evaluation menu, Kernel Configuration Options, Add, Kernel Name: *Kernel2*, OK.

(`` Developer`CellInformation `` [usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054270/879601) thanks to Arnoud Buzing.)

**runSolve.m**

```
NotebookPauseForEvaluation[nb_] := Module[{},
While[NotebookEvaluatingQ[nb],Pause[.25]]];

NotebookEvaluatingQ[nb_]:=Module[{},
SelectionMove[nb,All,Notebook];
Or@@Map["Evaluating"/.#&,Developer`CellInformation[nb]]
];

UsingFrontEnd[
nb = NotebookOpen["C:\\yourPath\\Solve.nb"];
SetOptions[nb, Evaluator -> "Kernel2"];
SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
SelectionEvaluate[nb]
NotebookPauseForEvaluation[nb];
NotebookSave[nb];
];

Quit[];
```

This can then be run manually or from a batch file, runSolve.bat

```
cd \Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.4
start MathKernel -noprompt -initfile "C:\yourPath\runSolve.m"
```

**runSolve.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal
PATH = C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.4\;%PATH%
echo Launching MathKernel
start MathKernel -noprompt -initfile "C:\yourPath\runSolve.m"
endlocal
```

Both these files can be plain text.

***Alternative version***

To run the notebook visibly so you can see it executing use this version.  It has a minor warning message detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626491/uncaught-throw-generated-by-jlink-or-usefrontend), but I prefer it since it is useful to see the evaluation progress.

**runSolve.m**

```
NotebookPauseForEvaluation[nb_] := Module[{},
While[NotebookEvaluatingQ[nb],Pause[.25]]];

NotebookEvaluatingQ[nb_]:=Module[{},
SelectionMove[nb,All,Notebook];
Or@@Map["Evaluating"/.#&,Developer`CellInformation[nb]]
];

Needs["JLink`"];

$FrontEndLaunchCommand = FileNameJoin[
{$InstallationDirectory, "Mathematica.exe"}];

UseFrontEnd[
nb = NotebookOpen["C:\\yourPath\\Solve.nb"];
SetOptions[nb, Evaluator -> "Kernel2"];
SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
SelectionEvaluate[nb]
NotebookPauseForEvaluation[nb];
NotebookSave[nb];
];

Quit[];
```

Comment: Excuse me. I am using LInux. Although I can alter the batch file to be bash friendly, the loop and ping section is not clear for me.

Comment: No. It doesn't work... I was trying hard to run it on linux. I am not an expert with Mathematica... As a cluster administrator, I was trying to help the users to be able to run their application via the terminal. Please see the updated post.

Comment: I have updated my answer.  (No extra lines required in Solve.nb now.)

Comment: Excuse me... I ran your script but my file name was solve.m and not Solve.m. I will update the answer soon

Comment: I ran it with `math`. There is no output. Please look at the updated post which shows the notebook. Does that produce an output and the math command doesn't show that? I want to be sure that the command is successfully run.